# How to change permissions from root user to all users?

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, terminal, root

I created a folder on the command line as the root user. Now I want to edit it and its contents in GUI mode. How do I change the permissions on it to allow me to do this?

Comment: You can use setfacl command.

Answer (score 81):

If I understand you correctly, fire up a terminal, navigate to one level above that directory, change to root and issue the command:

```
chown -R user:group directory/
```

This changes the ownership of `directory/` (and everything else within it) to the user `user` and the group `group`. Many systems add a group named after each user automatically, so you may want:

```
chown -R user:user directory/
```

After this, you can edit the tree under `directory/` and even change the permissions of `directory/` and any file/directory under it, from the GUI.

If you truly want *any* user to have full permissions on all files under `directory/` (which may be OK if this is your personal computer, but is definitely not recommended for multi-user environments), you can issue this:

```
chmod -R a+rwX directory/
```

as root.

Comment: How can I undo the last command you gave?

Comment: @TJonS The last command opens (almost) all permissions to everybody, so undoing it depends on which permissions you want to revoke.

Answer (score 24):

Just type:

```
chmod -R 777 directory/
```

and it will be available to all.

Comment: Don't give `777` to any directory!

Answer (score 7):

Just use this linux command

```
sudo chown -R :users your_directory
```

Answer (score 2):

how to change only root permission for the file.

```
$ sudo chmod 700 PathOfYourFile
```

If you want to change all permission for all  users then

```
$ sudo chmod 777 PathOfYourFile
```

table for different permission:
user group others

```
rwx  rwx   rwx = 111 111 111

rw-  rw-   rw- = 110 110 110

rwx  ---  --- = 111 000 000
```

and so on...

```
rwx = 111 in binary = 7

rw- = 110 in binary = 6

r-x = 101 in binary = 5

r-- = 100 in binary = 4
```